# How to increment the count in different screens in LCD?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I have 2 different screens on LCD connected with a single 8051 microcontroller. I want to increment the count on both screens present in the same position (1,0) on LCD when the button is pressed. Three buttons are used one for moving the cursor to that position and another for incrementing count and another for changing the screen. But when I pressed the button on the second screen it gets the `temp` value incremented, but I want the `temp1` value to be incremented.

How can I increment the second screen count with the same button?

Here, I have incremented the first screen count as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void display_screen1(void);
void display_screen2(void);
void change_screen(void);
void move_cursor(void);
void increment(void);
int set_cursor_position(uint_fast8_t row, uint_fast8_t col);

int temp = '2';
int temp1 = '5';
int first = 1;
int second = 0;
int count = 0;
unsigned char button0 = 0;
unsigned char button1 = 0;
unsigned char button2 = 0;

int set_cursor_position(uint_fast8_t row, uint_fast8_t col)
{
    if (row)
    {
        col |= 0x40;
    }
    col |= 0x80;
    lcd_cout(col);
    return 0;
}

void display_screen1(void)
{
    lcd_l2(0x80);       //position on LCD (1,0)
    lcd_dout(temp);    //displaying on LCD
}

void display_screen2(void)
{
    lcd_l2(0x80);
    lcd_dout(temp1);
}

void change_screen(void)
{
    if (button0 == 1)
    {     
       if(count == 0) {           
           count++;
           delay_msec(100);
           display_screen1();
           button0 = 0;
    }
       else if (count == 1) {
           display_screen2();
           count = 0;
           button0 = 0;
   }
}

void move_cursor(void)
{
    if (button1 == 1)
    {
        if (second > 1 && second <= 6)
        {
            first = 1;
            second = second + 1;
            if (second > 6)
                second = 2;
            set_cursor_position(first, second);
        }
        button1 = 0;
    }
}

void increment(void)
{
    if (button2 == 1)           //if button is pressed
    {   
            temp++;
            if (temp > 0x39)
                temp = 0x30;
            lcd_dout(temp);      
     }
    set_cursor_position(1, 0);
    button2 = 0;  
}
```

Comment: 1st, your source is not compilable, since multiple functions and variables are not defined. -- 2nd, you urgently need to choose a code style and stick to it, most importantly for indentation. (I have formatted your source for you.) Keeping the source formatted helps you so much to see logical errors. -- 3rd, learn about FSM, finite state machines. In the most simple form it is not more than a variable storing the "state" of your program, and some `switch` or `if` on this state to decide what to do. You can store the index of the display, and/or the position on the displays, and so on.

Comment: From your text it is not really clear how many 8051s you use. Is it just one, or do you have 2 microcontrollers in this project?

Comment: @thebusybee I have used 1 microcontroller. How can I store the index of the display? Any implementation? thank you.

Comment: Define a variable with a decent name, and use it to store the index.

Comment: @jack where are you trying to increment `temp1` ?

Comment: Your LCD likely uses the Hitachi HD44780 controller. If so, you will have an 80-character DRAM buffer that defines the characters for the display. The indexing is a bit different for a 16x2 or 20x4 display, but the buffer is the same. The easy way to do it is simply keep a `char[80]` array and update the indexes that correspond to the positions on screen 1 and screen2 as you like. The characters you update don't have to be visible at the time. Then you can simply write the updated character to the visible portion of the screen and the update on the 2nd screen will draw when you shift the LCD.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin your way is as: unsigned char Data[80] = "'080408100401"; and updating the index of Data[i]++ ,here i is the second screen index value .Is this way?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But it depends on whether you have a 16x2 or 20x4 display. For 16x2, your 80-char buffer is split `line[0]` `[0-15][16-32][33-40]` where each `[...]` is a screen worth of data for the line. Your `line[1]` is the same, but the DDRAM address for `line[1]` begins at `0x40h`. For a 20x4 display your first 80-char buffer does `line[0]` `[0-19]` and `line[2]` `[20-40]` and the rest does `line[1]` and `line[4]` with `line[1]` address being DDRAM `0x40h`.

Comment: See [HD44780 Datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am using a 16x2 display of the Hitachi HD44780 controller. this way incrementing both index when the button is pressed:unsigned char Data0[80] = "'08040810040167890886786788";
if (button0 == 1) {          
   temp[0]++;
   lcd_dout(temp[0]);
                        temp[16]++;
   lcd_dout(temp[16]);  
    
}

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. Your `lcd_dout()` is apparently writing the `unsigned char`. What isn't clear is what DDRAM address you are telling it to write to. You probably want to call `set_cursor_position()` before each write to move the cursor to the position you want to output the character. Otherwise, if it writes a screen-full at a time beginning with an address, you would need, e.g. `&temp[0]`. Note how your `set_cursor_position()` uses `col |= 0x40;` to add `0x40` to the position if it is the 2nd line (e.g. `line[1]`)

Comment: Your `lcd_cout()` function is your `commond-out` function while your `lcd_dout()` is your `data-out` function. (those are in the lcd source itself). You can write a single character to the DDRAM address, or write a specified no. of chars (just loop that many times calling the single-character out function incrementing the position in the buffer) or you can write a string out (just looping until the character is the `'\0'` character. It all works the same. Set the cursor position, and then start writing. Your code looks similar to a library I have.

Comment: Please don't change your source with the corrections you found. If the answer fits your needs, mark it. Leave the question intact for future readers to understand. You might want to read some of the [help] pages to recall how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

You should need a variable to record what currently used LCD.

Otherwise, `8051` can't increase the count on the correct LCD.

So you maybe try to add a variable in `void change_screen(void)`.

**Second**

Before increasing the count, `8051` needs to judge which LCD you are using.

So you need to add the judgment in `void increment(void)`

The concept is like below:

```
enum{
    LCD1,
    LCD2
}LCD_NUM;

bool SwitchLCD_flag=false;

void change_screen(void)
{
    if (ChangeLCD_button == 1)
    {
        ....
       // When pressed the button, switch the LCD_NUM.
       SwitchLCD_flag = !SwitchLCD_flag;

       switch(SwitchLCD_flag) {
           case 0:  
                  LCD_NUM = LCD1;
                  ...
                  break;
           case 1:
                  LCD_NUM = LCD2;
                  ...
                  break;       
        }
   }
}
```

**Third**

For now, `8051` knows which LCD is in use.

So you can write the increase function in the judge function.

The concept is like below:

```
void increment(void)
{
    if (Increase_button == 1)           
    {
        switch(LCD_NUM){
            case LCD1:
                LCD1_count++;
                break;
            case LCD2:
                LCD2_count++;
            break;
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And suggest you before programming, you can draw a simple flowchart to clear your code's structure and the relationship between each function.

Comment: as you have suggested the way, I have tried to implement as above, is it correct?

Comment: Your code can't just copy my example, you should change the variable name to fit your code, ex: `LCD_NUM` has not been defined in your code.
And what your `count` means? If you want to judge which LCD on use, you should use `count` into the `increment()` to judgement.
For `increment()`, the concept is correct, but the code of judge LCD part needs to modify.
You need to think well your code will how to work before you verify on the `8051`. If the result is not fit with your expectations, and find the root cause.

Comment: code of judge LCD part needs to modify. How the count is used to make the judgement? I didn't get that.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the LCD judgement concept is like above, maybe you can try it , and think the process flow whether is the same as your expectations.

Comment: sorry but it's not working as expected as it is coping the value of temp and incrementing value starting from the temp value when the screen is changed and the button is pressed for the increment of temp1.

Comment: Sorry, I have done some mistakes, `SwitchLCD_flag = !SwitchLCD_flag;` should be before the `switch block`, because the purpose is wanting to switch the LCD when pressing the button, so modified like this is more make sense.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, appreciated it.